# Python Defining more than one chunk group after tokenization

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, chunking

I have a code to tokenize sentences and then extract the patterns.The code is very popular these days for sentence tokenization and then pattern recognition using NLTK.

```
train_text = state_union.raw("2006-GWBush.txt")

with open('input.txt',"r",encoding="utf8") as g:
sample_text = g.read()

custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)

tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(sample_text)

def process_content():
try:
    for i in nltk.sent_tokenize(sample_text):
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
        tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)
        #print (tagged)
        chunkGram = r"""chunk: {<PRP><MD><RB><VB><.*><CD><NN>}"""   #1
        chunkGram = r"""punk: {<PRP><MD><VB><DT><NN><IN><DT><JJ><NN>}"""      #2         

        chunkParser = nltk.RegexpParser(chunkGram)
        chunked = chunkParser.parse(tagged)
        print (chunked)
        chunked.draw()

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))

process_content()
```

problem here is that the code knows to extract either  line #1 or #2 but not both.So just one of the chunk groups are detected.Why is that and how can I modify to code to get 2 or even more groups?

Thanks

Comment: Build a single string with both/all grammar rules. Each assignment to the variable `chunkGram` wipes out the earlier contents.